# How to set object to size of window?

Tags: jquery, object

I have currently tried setting up this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  

  <head>
    <script src="https://coinsh.red/u/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head> 

        <object width=$(window).width(); height=$(window).height(); data="<url-to-file"> 
            Sadly, your browser doesn’t fully support the html included in this page. 
        </object>

</html>
```

I am currently hosting some files on an alternative CDN and need to set a webpage to embed this file as the webpage.

**Question**: How do I set the object to be the size of the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for this. As long as `html` and `body` has a height of 100%. You can target your object element via CSS as well and set the height to 100%.

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

object {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <object data="<url-to-file"> 
        Sadly, your browser doesn’t fully support the html included in this page. 
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <object id="obj" data="<url-to-file>">
            Sadly, your browser doesn’t fully support the html included in this page. 
        </object>
        <script>
            $('#obj').height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

I added script that checks the size of a window and then sets object size. You can add some [resize events](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) in `script` that always set the correct size for an object.

I think it's less elegant than using CSS like [dw_ suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185992/4699618).